# Python dynamically import modules

Tags: python-3.x, import

I am trying to find the best practice for importing modules dynamically. I have multiple files in a specific folder called `providers` which contain a class `Updater` and all of them have the same objects.

This is the structure I have:

```yaml
main.py
|-providers:
  --__init__.py
  --plex.py
  --pihole.py
```

Each provider has 3 class objects: `get_latest_version`, `get_current_version`, `install`.

This is the contents of main.py file:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from Updater.plex import Updater as PlexUpdater
from Updater.pihole import Updater as PiholeUpdater

for provClass in [PlexUpdater, PiholeUpdater]:
    provider = provClass()
    latest_version = provider.get_latest_version()
    current_version = provider.get_current_version()
    provider.install()
```

I need to be able to create file on the providers folder and be automatically imported on the main file without explicitly importing myself. Could you suggest a way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found how to do this. On the init file I loaded all modules and returned them as a dictionary.

Code for `__init__.py`:

```py
from pkgutil import iter_modules
from pathlib import Path
from importlib import import_module

globals()['modules'] = {}

# iterate through the modules in the current package
package_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
for (_, module_name, _) in iter_modules([package_dir]):
    globals()['modules'][module_name] = getattr(import_module(f"{__name__}.{module_name}"), 'Updater')
```

The `main.py` changed into this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import providers

for provider_name, module in providers.modules.items():
    provider = module()
    latest_version = provider.get_latest_version()
    current_version = provider.get_current_version()
    provider.install()
```

Most helpful article was [this](https://julienharbulot.com/python-dynamical-import.html).

Comment: Note that you don't need `globals()`. You could just do `modules = {}` and `modules[module_name] = ...`.

Comment: Oh yeah. You are right. Thanks for pointing that out.